# How to compile Lex & yacc in Windows 7?

Tags: yacc, lex

How to complie these in a Windows 7 Pc?

```
% lex chl-n.1
% yacc -d chl-m.y
% cc -c 1ex.yy.c y.tab.c
% cc -0 example-m.n 1ex.yy.o y.tab.0 -11
```

is it like this?

```
flex my_code.l
bison -y -d my_code.y
gcc -c y.tab.c lex.yy.c
gcc y.tab.o lex.yy.o my_code.c -o my_code.exe
```

but my last code is not working, it says "gcc: my_code.c: No such file or Directory".
This is a example code from O'really Book (ch1-05 page36). C file is not generating.

Comment: try cygwin - see this http://www.eecg.utoronto.ca/~aamodt/ece242/cygwin.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cc and gcc are typical linux tools. They don't come installed in windows.

An easy way to get them is installing cygwin.

A step-by-step tutorial is available here

http://www.eecg.utoronto.ca/~aamodt/ece242/cygwin.html